# ReadOnlyException DataTable DataRow "Column X is read only."

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

I've got a short piece of code that originally created an **SqlDataAdapter** object over and over.

Trying to streamline my calls a little bit, I replaced the **SqlDataAdapter** with an **SqlCommand** and moved the **SqlConnection** outside of the loop.

Now, whenever I try to edit rows of data returned to my **DataTable**, I get a **ReadOnlyException** thrown that was not thrown before.

NOTE: I have a custom function that retrieves the employee's full name based on their ID. For simplicity here, I used "John Doe" in my example code below to demonstrate my point.

*ExampleQueryOld* works with the **SqlDataAdapter**; *ExampleQueryNew* fails with the **ReadOnlyException** whenever I try to write to an element of the **DataRow**:

- *ExampleQueryOld*

This works and has no issues:

```
public static DataTable ExampleQueryOld(string targetItem, string[] sqlQueryStrings) {
  DataTable bigTable = new DataTable();
  for (int i = 0; i < sqlQueryStrings.Length; i++) {
    string sqlText = sqlQueryStrings[i];
    DataTable data = new DataTable(targetItem);
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, Global.Data.Connection)) {
      try {
        da.Fill(data);
      } catch (Exception err) {
        Global.LogError(_CODEFILE, err);
      }
    }
    int rowCount = data.Rows.Count;
    if (0 < rowCount) {
      int index = data.Columns.IndexOf(GSTR.Employee);
      for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
        DataRow row = data.Rows[j];
        row[index] = "John Doe"; // This Version Works
      }
      bigTable.Merge(data);
    }
  }
  return bigTable;
}
```

- *ExampleQueryNew*

This example throws the ReadOnlyException:

```
public static DataTable ExampleQueryNew(string targetItem, string[] sqlQueryStrings) {
  DataTable bigTable = new DataTable();
  using (SqlConnection conn = Global.Data.Connection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sqlQueryStrings.Length; i++) {
      string sqlText = sqlQueryStrings[i];
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, conn)) {
        DataTable data = new DataTable(targetItem);
        try {
          if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
          }
          using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            data.Load(reader);
          }
        } catch (Exception err) {
          Global.LogError(_CODEFILE, err);
        } finally {
          if ((cmd.Connection.State & ConnectionState.Open) != 0) {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
          }
        }
        int rowCount = data.Rows.Count;
        if (0 < rowCount) {
          int index = data.Columns.IndexOf(GSTR.Employee);
          for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
            DataRow row = data.Rows[j];
            try {
              // ReadOnlyException thrown below: "Column 'index'  is read only."
              row[index] = "John Doe";
            } catch (ReadOnlyException roErr) {
              Console.WriteLine(roErr.Message);
            }
          }
          bigTable.Merge(data);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return bigTable;
}
```

Why can I write to the **DataRow** element in one case, but not in the other?

Is it because the **SqlConnection** is still open or is the **SqlDataAdapter** doing something behind the scene?

Comment: There are a few users on here that don't like me, I guess.

Comment: It's probably the `DataTable.Load(IReader)` setting the column as readonly.  Can you just set `ReadOnly` to false for all the columns?

Comment: Maybe! ...if I knew where to find such a `ReadOnly` property. :)

Comment: Since `DataTable`, `DataRow`, and `DataRow item` have no `ReadOnly` property, I tried modifying the `DataTable.Load(IReader)` command with `DataTable.Load(IReader, LoadOption.Upsert)`, `DataTable.Load(IReader, LoadOption.Upsert)` (the default), and `DataTable.Load(IReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)`, but I got the same results: `ReadOnlyException`.

Comment: foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in tab.Columns) col.ReadOnly = false;

Answer (score 107, accepted):

using `DataAdapter.Fill` does not load the database schema, which includes whether a column is a primary key or not, and whether a column is read-only or not. To load the database schema, use `DataAdapter.FillSchema`, but then that's not your questions.

using `DataReader` to fill a table loads the schema. So, the `index` column is read-only (probably because it's the primary key) and that information is loaded into the `DataTable`. Thereby preventing you from modifying the data in the table.

I think @k3b got it right; by setting `ReadOnly = false`, you should be able to write to the data table.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in tab.Columns) col.ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: Mr. Pieng: A follow up, after a year. Is there a way to **unload** or **discard** the schema after the `DataReader` retrieves the data?

Comment: @jp2code You can probably create a new Table and copy just the data without the schema info. If it's only a specific property that you want to change such as the read-only flag, you might be better off just setting the value of that property.

Comment: I already used my up votes for today, but virtual +1 for this answer. I was fighting with this for couple of hours before I found out that one of columns was read only. Now my little DataGridView wok like a charm! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I kept getting the same exception while trying different approaches.  What finally worked for me was to set the column's ReadOnly property to false and change the value of the **Expression** column instead of row[index] = "new value";

Answer (score 1):

## In VB, don't pass a read-only DataRow Item by reference

The likelihood that you'll run into this is low, but I was working on some VB.NET code and got the `ReadOnlyException`.

I ran into this issue because the code was passing the DataRow Item to a Sub ByRef. Just the act of passing-byref triggers the exception.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {
        .ReadOnly = True,
        .ColumnName = "Name",
        .DataType = GetType(Integer)
    })

    dt.Rows.Add(4)

    Try
        DoNothing(dt.Rows(0).Item("Name"))
        Console.WriteLine("All good")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try 

End Sub

Sub DoNothing(ByRef item As Object) 
End Sub
```

#### Output

`Column 'Name' is read only`

## C-sharp

You can't even write code like this in C# . `DoNothing(ref dt.Rows[0].Item["Name"])` gives you a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

open the yourdataset.xsd file of your data set. click on the table or object and click on the specific column which readonly property need to be changed.
its simple solutions.